# Validate Specific Alphanumeric Format

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, alphanumeric

I'm struggling to get this to work. Basically, I'm trying to create an excel formula that will look at a value e.g. RFC12345678 and return whether the format is valid or not. The conditions are:

- Has to begin with RFC
- Followed by 8 numbers

If it meets those conditions, return "Valid", if not, return "Invalid".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AND()` with three checks:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(A1)=11,LEFT(A1,3)="RFC",ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(A1,8))),"Valid","Invalid")
```

- The first makes sure there are no extra characters, so `RFC123456789` does not return TRUE;
- The second test for `RFC` in the beginning;
- The last test if the right 8 are numeric.

If your check needs to be case-sensitive, change to:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(A1)=11,EXACT(LEFT(A1,3),"RFC"),ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(A1,8))),"Valid","Invalid")
```